# Ubuntu 13.10 unity won't load from this morning

Tags: unity

I turned on my pc this morning and unity will not load at all. I have tried loading it manually using ctrl+alt+f1 and all i got from it was the following:-

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/r600_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/r600_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2014-06-03 10:55:31 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Autopilot.Introspection' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-06-03 10:55:31 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Debug.Logging' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
compiz (unityshell) - Error: GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object not supported
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin initScreen failed: unityshell
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: unityshell
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x4000006
  Serial number of failed request:  9909
  Current serial number in output stream:  9913
```

It was all working fine yesterday but this morning there was nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem as you Jarmand83. Have you been able to find a workaround? Everything was working fine yesterday for me as well. I've tried resetting unity following instructions here (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/reset-unity-and-compiz-in-ubuntu-13-10/) but to no avail

Comment: From what i have found it is a problem with libgl1-mesa-dri as there seems to be broken files in the amd and intel graphics. When it will be fixed i dont know and i cannot seem to revert back at the moment either so when i figure it out i will post here.

Comment: Not really a solution to the problem, but I managed to work around it by upgrading to 14.04. Which - as I read on another post - has an updated version of Unity. My windows and taskbars display correctly now. Needless to say, I wasn't very happy with Ubuntu yesterday

Comment: Just update to 14.04.

Comment: I ended up just doing a backup of files then a fresh install as when attempting to upgrade it failed and set my ubuntu partition to unmount which left me with the initramfs prompt. Still all ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug that affects many users, me too (13.10). I solved with this:

[Unity not Working 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475683/unity-not-working-14-04)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! your answer would be far more helpful if you noted which answer on http://askubuntu.com/questions/475683/unity-not-working-14-04 worked for you with 13.10. Please be more specific. Thank you.